# Creating a "puff of smoke" effect in iOS game

Tags: ios

I would like to have some text appear and disappear in a puff of smoke effect in an iPhone game.  For example, when someone scores points, I want to show the new points that were added.  It should appear in a puff of smoke and disappear within a second or two.

How do I create that?

Comment: I would go for particle effects, which in iOS are created using CAParticleLayer/CAEmitterLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Particle Designer from 71 Squared. It costs about $7.99 and includes easy code generation and integration. There are some pre-configured smoke effects available in the shared library.

http://particledesigner.71squared.com

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have kind of "cheap" effects using particles, but you'll have a good control over the animation (velocity, scaling, acceleration...).
Another way to go is to use multiple images of smoke and overlay them, then launch an UIView animation with random properties for rotating, scaling and timing.